# Display two prices if user is logged in. Change varible price as from. Display the custom price variation for a variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using "Enable sale price for logged users and regular price for unlogged users in Woocommerce" first function code, that hides sales price. That way I can use sales price and regular price for logged in vs none logged in users and it Works great.

The problem I am running into is that it always hides the sale price, but if user is logged in is should be display two prices (sale price and regular price):

For solution I am using the following

// Display the sales price for a simple product only if_user_is_logged_in /

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_get_price_html', 20, 2 );

function custom_get_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('simple') )
    {
        if( is_user_logged_in() )
            $regular_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );
            
        else
            $active_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) );

        if( $active_price > 0 )
            $price = wc_price($active_price) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    // Return $price
    return $price;
}
```

//Change the display of prices for variable products to "from the minimum price" and "from the minimum sale price" for if_user_is_logged_in /

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom1_variation_price', 20, 2 );
 
function custom1_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
 
    $min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true );
    $max_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max', true );
 
    
    if ( ! ( $min_regular_price == $max_regular_price && $min_sale_price == $max_sale_price ) ) {
    
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            if ( $min_sale_price < $min_regular_price ) {
                $price = sprintf( 'от <del>%1$s</del><ins>%2$s</ins>', wc_price( $min_regular_price ), wc_price( $min_sale_price ) );
            } else {
                $price = sprintf( 'от %1$s', wc_price( $min_regular_price ) );
            }
        }
        else {
            if ( $min_sale_price < $min_regular_price ) {
                $price = sprintf( 'от %1$s', wc_price( $min_regular_price ), wc_price( $min_sale_price ) );
            } else {
                $price = sprintf( 'от %1$s', wc_price( $min_regular_price ) );
            }
        }
            
    }
 
    return $price;
 
}
```

// Display the custom price variation for a variable product as ['regular price'] if a guest. And display custom price variation ['sale price' - 'regular price (cross out)'] if user_is_logged_in /

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_variation_price', 10, 3);
function custom_variation_price( $price, $product, $variation ) {

    $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) );

    if( is_user_logged_in() )
        $reg_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $variation, array( 'price' => $variation->get_regular_price() ) );
    else 
        $price['price_html'] = wc_price( $reg_price );
    
    
    // Return $price
    return $price;
}
```

1. The code works, but I'm not sure if it is correct.
2. My regular custom variation price for guests in variable products is not displayed correctly.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Hard to tell from the question. But if you are working with php to show the badge, perhaps you are looking for the is_user_logged_in() function?

Comment: @7uc1f3r I'm sorry, I'm just a beginner. I wrote what I was trying to do.

Comment: @ralf im update my topic

Comment: 1. return should not be conditional. In this case probably either the price or empty.

Comment: 2. I see nothing obvious. Too much code. Have you tried with a debugger? Without one and more context I don't see what's going in and out etc.

Comment: @ralf 1. it wok
2.

Comment: @ralf I completely reworked the code and changed the task.

Comment: @7uc1f3r I completely reworked the code and changed the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try filters

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_prices_regular_price', 'custom_variation_price', 99, 3 );